# htaccess, block access a url with parameters

Tags: apache-2.4, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, rules

If I want to block access to `example.com/path/?xxxx` (`xxxx` is variable), but allow access to `example.com/path/`, how should I write it in my `.htaccess`?

Comment: Are these urls valid ? Are there files there ?

Comment: Ex: domain.com/someone/someone.php real and valid url. Attackers use domain.com/someone/someone.php?ddfdfd to bring down my site. If I write that parameter after a valid url, it does not cause a 404 error, it loads the url domain.com/someone/someone.php

Answer (score 1):

You can block access (eg. trigger a 404 Not Found) when a specific path (`/path/`) is requested with any query string using mod_rewrite at the top of the root `.htaccess` file.

For example:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
RewriteRule ^path/$ - [R=404]
```

The above matches the URL `/path/` exactly. (Note there is no slash prefix on the URL-path matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern* - the first argument.)

To block all URLs that contain any query string then change the `RewriteRule` *pattern* to just `^` (simply a start of string assertion, so it's successful for any URL-path). For example:

```
:
RewriteRule ^ - [R=404]
```